# Just started with Haskell. What's wrong with my set building notation?

Tags: haskell, set

I'm very excited with what I've seen of Haskell, but I'm already not quite getting list comprehensions.

If I want to find the truth set of something like:

P(x): x ^ 2 < 3

Why does the expression [x | x ^ 2 < 3] return []?  Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a source list for `x`, e.g.

```
[x | x <- [0.01, 0.02 .. 3], x ^ 2 < 3]
```

Haskell does not just generate values from a type, you have to provide a source of data.

Answer (score 6):

What you have shown in your question, `[x | x ^ 2 < 3]`, shouldn't even compile.  I suspect you have typed this into the interpreter after having defined 'x' at some point.  For example:

```
 Prelude> let x = 3
 Prelude> [x | x ^ 2 < 3] 
 []
```

In the above the list comprehension reads as 'the list of elements "x" such that the square of "X" is less than three'.  Obviously this can only end up with zero or one elements.  We can see the case where it produces one element in the below:

```
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude> [x | x ^ 2 < 3] 
[1]
```

Your desire to get a set of ALL elements requires you to define an input (I'm ignoring the fact that this is a LIST and not a set - but it is important so if you didn't realize that then look into it).  For example, the naturals:

```
Prelude> take 10 [x | x <- [0..], x ^ 2 < 3]
[0,1^CInterrupted.
```

This computation is a little closer.  For each value in `0, 1, 2...` test if its square is less than three and (if so) return it as the next element of the list.  Unfortunately, list comprehension preserves no knowledge about the structure of the domain - numbers from 2 upward will be tested (until the end of our input list, which in this case is the max bound of `Int`) giving it the appearance of non-termination.

Instead, we can define a domain and, knowing the behavior of our predicate, only accept elements while it holds:

```
Prelude> takeWhile (\x -> x^2 < 3) [0..]
[0,1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation